# Calling a function with array as an argument

Tags: javascript

pls I want this function to loop through any array and output a new array base on the logic written but am only getting the initial array when I call the function with the array as argument, pls I need help. Below is the code

```
const scores = [35, 68, 70, 38];
const scores1 = [89, 42, 33];
function gradingStudents(...grades) {
  const newScores = grades.map(function (grade) {
    if (grade + 2 >= 40 && grade % 5 >= 3) {
      return grade % 5 == 3 ? grade + 2 : grade + 1;
    } else if (grade + 2 >= 40 && grade % 5 < 3) {
      return grade;
    } else {
      return grade;
    }
  });
  return newScores;
}
console.log(gradingStudents(scores1));
```

Comment: You're passing an array as your parameter, so you don't need to use the rest operator (...), which is used when destructuring the array into multiple variables. With the rest operator, you get an array of the parameters not destructured, which means grades becomes [scores1] instead of just scores1, which is already an array. Remove the `...` (just `function gradingStudents(grades)`), and things should change. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Rest Paramanter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)** `(...)` is used when you are handling with dynamic number of arguments. Here you are passing only one argument to the function. Remove the `...` from the function param and your function will work as expected.

```js
const scores = [35, 68, 70, 38];
const scores1 = [89, 42, 33];
function gradingStudents(grades) {
  const newScores = grades.map(function (grade) {
    if (grade + 2 >= 40 && grade % 5 >= 3) {
      return grade % 5 == 3 ? grade + 2 : grade + 1;
    } else if (grade + 2 >= 40 && grade % 5 < 3) {
      return grade;
    } else {
      return grade;
    }
  });
  return newScores;
}
console.log(gradingStudents(scores1));
```

If you are handling the function using Rest Paramanter syntax as you did now, the parameter in the function written as `...grades` will combine all the paramaters in the function to a single array. Which means your paramater `scores1` will be there inside the `grades` array as in the below console.

```js
const scores1 = [89, 42, 33];
function gradingStudents(...grades) {
  // grades will be an array with scores1 as a sigle element in 0th index
  console.log(grades)
}
gradingStudents(scores1);
```

Looping through `grades` in the above condition, the each node will be an array which will not satisfy any of the if statement, hence it will return the array itself. Thats why you are getting the output as an array with the parementer as the single node.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring your function with [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), you're expected to give your data as multiple arguments that will be automatically wrapped in an array

When giving it an array, you'l get a nested array

```js
function restParamFunc(...params) {
  console.log(params)
}
restParamFunc([1, 2])
```

You should either transform the rest parameters to a classic parameter

```js
function restParamFunc(params) {
  console.log(params)
}
restParamFunc([1, 2])
```

or use array destructuring when calling the function

```js
function restParamFunc(...params) {
  console.log(params)
}
restParamFunc(...[1, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are returning *grade* if the first condition didn't meet. The rest operator is not needed. You can write it as follow:

```
function gradingStudents(grades) {
        const newScores = grades.map(function (grade) {
            if (grade + 2 >= 40 && grade % 5 >= 3) {
                return grade % 5 == 3 ? grade + 2 : grade + 1;
            }else {
                return grade;
            }
       });
       return newScores;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` also

```js
const scores = [35, 68, 70, 38];
const scores1 = [89, 42, 33];

function gradingStudents(grades) {
   let newScore = [];
   grades.forEach(function (grade) {
    if (grade + 2 >= 40 && grade % 5 >= 3) {
      grade = grade % 5 == 3 ? grade + 2 : grade + 1;
      newScore.push(grade);
    } else if (grade + 2 >= 40 && grade % 5 < 3) {
      newScore.push(grade);
    } else {
      newScore.push(grade);
    }
  });
  return newScore;
}

console.log(gradingStudents(scores));
console.log(gradingStudents(scores1));
```